# An integral of a rational function with high degrees: Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(x^4 + 1)^2}{x^{12} + 1}dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Calculate: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(x^4 + 1)^2}{x^{12} + 1}dx.$$

What I have tried is to divide both numerator and denominator with $x^4 + 1$ and then get two following integrals, because of parity of the integrand (nothing else worked for me): $$2\int_0^\infty \frac{x^4 + 1}{(x^4 - \sqrt3x^2 + 1)(x^4 + \sqrt3x^2 + 1)}dx = $$ $$ = \int_0^\infty \frac1{x^4 - \sqrt3x^2 + 1}dx + \int_0^\infty\frac1{x^4 + \sqrt3x^2 + 1}dx = $$ $$ = \int_0^\infty \frac1{(x^2 - \frac{\sqrt3}2)^2 + \frac14}dx + \int_0^\infty \frac1{(x^2 + \frac{\sqrt3}2)^2 + \frac14}dx.$$
I don't see what would be continuation of this. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you for any help. Appreciate it.

Comment: This problem is begging to be attacked with complex analysis.  But since that is off the table.  Each of those integrals is some sort of $\arctan$ function.  Try the substitution $x = \frac 12 \tan \theta + \frac {\sqrt 3}{2}$ for one integral and $x = \frac 12 \tan \theta - \frac {\sqrt 3}{2}$ for the other.

Comment: See  the answer from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454884/how-to-solve-the-integral-displaystyle-int-infty-infty-fracx412/2454947#2454947

Comment: Complex analysis is the most efficient tool here. Yet, you can continue with the decomposition into simple elements by observing that $$x^4 \pm \sqrt{3} + 1 = (x^2+1)^2 - (2 \mp \sqrt{3})x^2.$$ You recognize a difference of two squares, so can you factorize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**Hint:** For integrals of rational functions of even polynomials over the real line, the following substitution can come in handy:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(x^{4}+1\right)^{2}}{x^{12}+1}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(x^{4}+1\right)^{2}}{\left(x^{4}+1\right)\left(x^{8}-x^{4}+1\right)}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{4}+1}{x^{8}-x^{4}+1}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{4}+1}{x^{8}-x^{4}+1}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(x^{2}+x^{-2}\right)}{x^{2}\left(x^{4}+x^{-4}-1\right)}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(x^{2}+x^{-2}\right)}{\left(x^{4}+x^{-4}-1\right)};~~~\small{\left[x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(x^{2}+x^{-2}\right)}{x^{2}\left(x^{4}+x^{-4}-1\right)}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(x^{2}+x^{-2}\right)}{\left(x^{4}+x^{-4}-1\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{\left(x^{2}+x^{-2}\right)}{\left(x^{4}+x^{-4}-1\right)}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2\left(4y^{2}+2\right)}{\left(16y^{4}+16y^{2}+1\right)};~~~\small{\left[\frac{x^{-1}-x}{2}=y\iff x=\sqrt{y^{2}+1}-y\right]}.\\
\end{align}$$

Note that we have cut the degrees of the polynomials in half and still have all integer coefficients. This could be considered an advantage over the brute-force partial fraction method if you're looking to avoid messy factorizations.

Comment: I might ask a dumb question. This is a rational function, but Wolfram Alpha solves the integrals as series by $\omega$ . What does that mean?

Comment: @NemanjaBeric Can you provide me a link to your Wolfram Alpha output?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ob3gahmye19ijy3/Screenshot_2017-10-02-22-47-18.png?dl=0

Comment: Same happens when doing other integrals.

Comment: @NemanjaBeric Look at the condition underneath the summation symbol, which says $\omega$ is a root of an 8th degree polynomial. The summation  is then over all $8$ roots of the given polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the rational degrees with successive  substitutions as follows
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(x^{4}+1)^{2}}{x^{12}+1}dx=&\ 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4}+1}{x^{8}-x^{4}+1}\overset{x\to\frac1x}{dx}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(x^{4}+1)(x^2+1)}{x^{8}-x^{4}+1}
\overset{ x-\frac1x\to x}{ dx} \\
=& \ 2\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2+2}{x^4+4x^2+1} \overset{x\to\frac1x}{dx}= 3\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+4x^2+1}
\overset{x-\frac1x\to x}{ dx} \\
=&\ 6\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^2+6}dx
=\sqrt{\frac32}\pi
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The difference of two squares $a^2-b^2$ can be factored as $(a-b)(a+b)$. A sum of two squares $a^2+b^2$ can be thought of as $a^2-(ib)^2$...

Comment: This is a problem in real analysis. We have not worked with complex analysis yet. Is there something I am missing? Thank you anyway

Comment: @NemanjaBeric It's not _really_ going to be complex analysis like - pretty much everything can be treated as a real number. I'm pretty sure there is a different solution, but, especially if you want to continue with partial fraction decomposition, this is probably close to the nicest one.

Comment: This seems too hard. Do you have a better idea to start with?  I am really stuck with this, and this is something I got for workout on my own, or for asking question, but I have to understand it. It is for a grade on my college. Thank you

Comment: @NemanjaBeric I don't know of a simpler way to do this problem. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Any rational function can always be integrated by decomposing it into partial fractions. In this case this decomposition is particularly simple.
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{x^4-\sqrt{3} x^2+1} &=& \frac{1}{x^2-\theta_+} \cdot \frac{1}{\theta_+-\theta_-} + \frac{1}{x^2-\theta_-} \cdot \frac{1}{\theta_--\theta_+}\\
\frac{1}{x^4+\sqrt{3} x^2+1} &=& \frac{1}{x^2-\lambda_+} \cdot \frac{1}{\lambda_+-\lambda_-} + \frac{1}{x^2-\lambda_-} \cdot \frac{1}{\lambda_--\lambda_+} 
\end{eqnarray}
where $\theta_\pm=(\sqrt{3}\pm \imath)/2$ and $\lambda_\pm=(-\sqrt{3}\pm \imath)/2$.
Therefore 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^4-\sqrt{3} x^2+1}&=& \frac{\pi}{\imath} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{-\sqrt{3}-\imath}{2}}}\\
\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^4+\sqrt{3} x^2+1}&=& \frac{\pi}{\imath} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{+\sqrt{3}-\imath}{2}}}
\end{eqnarray}
Now by using simple complex analysis we get the final result:
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(x^4+1)^2}{x^{12}+1} dx = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\pi
\end{equation}

Answer (score -2):

More a comment than an answer:

According to Wolfy,
the indefinite integrals
involve arctan and
complex values.
But the definite integrals
come out like this:

$\int_0^∞ \dfrac{dx}{x^4 - \sqrt{3} x^2 + 1}  
= \frac12 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}} π≈3.0345
$
and
$\int_0^∞ \dfrac{dx}{x^4 + \sqrt{3} x^2 + 1} dx = \dfrac{π}{2 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}}
≈0.8131
$